# combo - select enable / disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I have 3 combobox (select) and I need to enable the third one just if I choose an option from the first.

- categories (enable)
- subcategories (disable)
- grapes (disable)

If I choose `Wines` from `categories` I need to enable `grapes`

```
$('#subcategories').attr('disabled','disabled');
$('#grapes').attr('disabled','disabled');

$("#categories").change(function () {
$("#categories option:selected").each(function () {
    var v_elegido=$(this).val();    
    $('#subcategories').removeAttr('disabled');

    if($(this).val() == "Vinos")  {
        $('#grapes').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#grapes').attr('disabled','disabled');
    }

    $.post("subcategories.php", { elegido: v_elegido }, function(data){
        $("#subcategories").html(data);
    });  


});




 <?php if ($campo == 'varietales') { ?>    

    <div class="col_texto" align="right"><?php echo $campo ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="varietal" style="visibility:visible;">
        <select name="varietales" id="varietales">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <?php
            $conn = DataBase::getInstance();
                $rel=false;
                $relacion='_'.$campo;
                $conn->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `_'.$campo.'` ORDER BY id ASC');
                if ($conn->len()==0){
                    $rel=true;
                    $relacion=$campo;
                    $conn->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `'.$campo.'` ORDER BY id ASC');
                }
                if ($conn->len()==0){
                    $rel=true;
                    $relacion=$campo.'s';
                    $conn->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `'.$campo.'s` ORDER BY id ASC');
                }
                if ($conn->len()>0){
                $rs = $conn->loadObjectList();
                foreach($rs as $valor){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $valor->id ?>"><?php echo $valor->titulo ?></option>
            <?php 
                }}?>
            </select> 
      </div>      
         <?php } else { ?>
    <?php if ($campo == 'bodegas') { ?>    

    <div class="col_texto" align="right"  style="visibility:visible;"><?php echo $campo ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <div>
        <select name="bodegas" id="bodegas">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <?php
            $conn = DataBase::getInstance();
                $rel=false;
                $relacion='_'.$campo;
                $conn->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `_'.$campo.'` ORDER BY id ASC');
                if ($conn->len()==0){
                    $rel=true;
                    $relacion=$campo;
                    $conn->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `'.$campo.'` ORDER BY id ASC');
                }
                if ($conn->len()==0){
                    $rel=true;
                    $relacion=$campo.'s';
                    $conn->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `'.$campo.'s` ORDER BY id ASC');
                }
                if ($conn->len()>0){
                $rs = $conn->loadObjectList();
                foreach($rs as $valor){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $valor->id ?>"><?php echo $valor->titulo ?></option>
            <?php 
                }}?>
            </select> 
      </div>      
         <?php } else { ?>

   <?php if ($campo == 'subcategorias') { ?>    

    <div class="col_texto" align="right"><?php echo $campo ?>:&nbsp;</div>
  <div>
        <select name="<?php echo $campo ?>" id="<?php echo $campo ?>">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <?php
            $conn = DataBase::getInstance();
                $rel=false;
                $relacion='_'.$campo;
                $conn->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `_'.$campo.'` ORDER BY id ASC');
                if ($conn->len()==0){
                    $rel=true;
                    $relacion=$campo;
                    $conn->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `'.$campo.'` ORDER BY id ASC');
                }
                if ($conn->len()==0){
                    $rel=true;
                    $relacion=$campo.'s';
                    $conn->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `'.$campo.'s` ORDER BY id ASC');
                }
                if ($conn->len()>0){
                $rs = $conn->loadObjectList();
                foreach($rs as $valor){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $valor->id ?>"><?php echo $valor->titulo ?></option>
            <?php 
                }}?>
            </select>
    </div>        


         <?php  } else { ?> 



         <div class="col_texto" align="right"><?php echo $campo ?>:&nbsp;</div>
         <div>
        <select name="categorias" id="categorias">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <?php
            $conn = DataBase::getInstance();
                $rel=false;
                $relacion='_'.$campo;
                $conn->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `_'.$campo.'` ORDER BY id ASC');
                if ($conn->len()==0){
                    $rel=true;
                    $relacion=$campo;
                    $conn->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `'.$campo.'` ORDER BY id ASC');
                }
                if ($conn->len()==0){
                    $rel=true;
                    $relacion=$campo.'s';
                    $conn->setQuery('SELECT * FROM `'.$campo.'s` ORDER BY id ASC');
                }
                if ($conn->len()>0){
                $rs = $conn->loadObjectList();
                foreach($rs as $valor){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $valor->id ?>"><?php echo $valor->titulo ?></option>
            <?php 
                }}?>
            </select>
           </div>  

         <?php } ?>      
         <?php } ?>          
         <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

so all you need to do is get the val.. and set the disabled property accordingly

```
$("#categories").change(function(){
    $('#grapes').prop('disabled',$(this).val() != 'Vinos');
});
```

this is assuming you have values for your options and the third option in you first select is 'Vinos'

[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is also the preferred method to set the disabled property since jQuery 1.6+

> The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method

Comment: @Maru what's not working?  Can you create a jsfiddle showing what the problem is?

Comment: I edited my code and added my combo.
option "Vinos" keep disable

Comment: I'm confused.  If the first option is "Vinos", then keep disable?  or is it the other way around http://jsfiddle.net/HKAv9/

Comment: The first combo is "categorias", the second is "subcategorias" and th third is "varietales".

Subcategorias and Varietales are disable.

When I choose any category, subcategorias is enable (I don't have problem with this)

But, if Categorias = Vinos I need to enable "Varietales" also.